# migration from bootstrap3 to bootstrap 5

Tags: css, sass, less, css-transitions, css3pie

I have build a website in bootstrap 3. I started to convert it to bootstrap 5. everything is break on my website, is there any easy way to convert from bootstrap 3 to bootstrap 5. or is there any alternative way.

Answer (score 8):

The migration from Bootstrap 3 to Bootstrap 5 is a huge change, since Bootstrap 3 has been around since 2013.

I do not think there is an easy way to convert Bootstrap 3 to Bootstrap 5, due to many major changes and additions.

However, I would suggest you to go through the migration guides for more enlightenment.

v3 -> v4: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration

v4 -> v5: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/migration

Comment: For going from 3.x to 4.x, I've found the class change list provided [on this page](http://upgrade-bootstrap.bootply.com/) to be quite helpful, too.